# Regular expression to match letters, numbers, and certain symbols

Tags: php, regex

I need to validate a username in PHP. It can be:

- Letters (upper and lower case)
- Numbers
- Any of these symbols :.,?!@
- Up to 15 characters OR 16 if the last character is one of the following #$^ (it can also be 15 or less with one of these 3 characters at the end only)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9:.,?!@]{3,15}[#$^]?$/
```

then refine it to your needs. Try to see if you need escaping of the special char, but you should get the idea.

This means: from a to z, from A to Z, from 0 to 9 and :.,?!@ repeated from 3 to 15 times, optionally followed by one among #$^

Comment: Got it: `/^[A-Za-z0-9:\.,\?!@]{1,15}[#\$\^]?$/` Thanks for that. Now I just need to find out if there are any other special characters I need to allow.